# Z-index for relatively positioned elements?

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-position

I have an element, which I have tried to place on top of another with this:

```
<div id="foo1"></div>
<div id="foo2"></div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#foo1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
}
#foo2 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: -300px;
}
```

But now `#foo2` is going underneath `#foo1`. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making them absolute instead of relative would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
#foo1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;
}
#foo2 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: -300px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1000;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add position: relative; to each of the styles, as stated here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

(They can both have relative positioning)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with positioning

```
#foo1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
 background-color:red;position:relative
}
#foo2 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
 background-color:green; position:absolute; top:0; left:0
}​
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/fckrA/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could place one div inside the other, and apply position: relative to parent and position: absolute to child. Child would appear above parent and aligned to top-left corner.